# Unit testing a program which has no output by itself

Tags: unit-testing, cobol

I have been asked to test (unit testing stage) program 'B' which is called by program 'A', controls something then calls program 'C' which does have some output. 'B' has no output by itself.

My question is : Should I debug program 'B' in isolation and compare the communication area between 'B' and 'C' to what is expected ?

Or should I run program 'A' and compare output of 'C' to  what is expected ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you could do that, or put displays in the programs then look at the log after it has completes

Comment: @saggingrufus you are right in that using displays will allow me to get the value of the communication area without using a debugger. But it also means having to, after tests completion, delete displays and recompile the program. That's why I had not included this in my question. However It is a pragmatic solution to my problem that I will discuss with my colleagues.

Comment: That's the route I have personally gone down. It works, but if you have the use of a debugging tool I would recommend that. That's the only thing I can think of aside from the solution you already proposed in the question. There are some pretty smart people who hang around the COBOL tag. Maybe one of them will have a better solution.

Comment: @saggingrufus I checked => in my case displays aren't an option.

Comment: Is there anyway to get a hold of a debugging tool like Xpediter or Viasoft?

Comment: Actually, I use xpediter everyday. This is the debugging tool I talked about. However after asking some questions,  I have just been asked to do unit testing via running the first program in the chain, with the right parameters. I feel it is not quite unit testing but this is how it has been done for years in my case.

Comment: you should be able to run it as normal, but put a break point in program B this will allow to use to program A, but when program B is invoked, you will walk through the code in xpediter until program B is complete. Then program C should run after the xpediter session. You should be OK. Just don't change any values in xpediter while you are in the active session

Comment: Nevertheless, whatever the 'solution' applied in my case, I wish someone with more knowledge and experience than me would put together in an answer some advices about best practices about unit testing such type of program with no obvious input nor output because such information would be, IMHO, quite valuable.

Comment: You could setup a stub program that calls program C an tests the results, but you are probably better of following the current strategies.

Comment: You are unlikely to get wide concordance on what "unit testing" means. Which makes your question too broad unless you include what it specifically means at your site. I'd expect the programmer to test with the stub method already suggested by @BruceMartin, and the various "testing" people to be testing the "program" (made up of multiple programs) as a whole, which should also exercise the functionality of the sub-program. There must be some effect of the sub-program, else why bother to CALL it anyway?

Comment: Of course, this sub-program (B) does something. It is calling one specific sub-sub-program (C) according to what order it has received from the main program (A), and the rules implemented in B. The problem is, the definition of unit testing seems different for each analyst I am working with. And in this specific case, although I have been asked to go with the second solution I mentioned in my question (and I will go with it), I am still bothered and thinking the debugger-solution is more unit-testing-like. I was simply seeking an expert's advice on this specific case, for when I'll be analyst.

Comment: To be completely honest, If I was the person doing the testing I would do both of the suggestions you gave above. First I would test with the debuuger to ensure all of my commareas have the intended data. Then, I would check the output of the program C. When someone asks me to do a unit testing, I will use all of the tools available to me and perform the same test using different methods of checking the output. But as @BillWoodger said, unit testing can mean something different to pretty much everyone

Comment: With a "stub" or a "harness", a sub-program can be tested, and repeatably tested, in isolation from its use. For the program-as-a-whole, the testing of the sub-program may only be a sub-set, because something prevents the path that actually has the CALL being taken. Different methodologies, frameworks and strategies, and the local interpretations, are why exactly how, and how much, cannot be told in a general sense. Too many inputs.

Comment: If you see this as answer I'll re-post it, otherwise the "too broad" issue applies to the question :-)

For "unit-testing": write a test stub that calls the SUB multiple times with different input parameters and display the result.

For "testing that it works inside": add `DISPLAY` statements (ideally with a specific device) that won't be done in normal work flows by setting the indicator column 7 to `D`. These statements will only be done if your source is recompiled with `SOURCE-COMPUTER stuff WITH DEBUGGING MODE.`

Comment: I think this is a good answer. Although I went down the road of 'unit testing that looks like integration testing', I'd prefer your idea.

Comment: And the 'stub' method has the advantage of being a third method.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when one module did not return a feedback, a good practice is to return a least a success indicator.

```
 01 ERROR. 
    03 CD-ERROR    PIC 9(04) COMP-5.
 01 INPUT.
    ...
```

If **A** >> **B** >> **C**, then **A** have to receive a `CD-ERROR=0` indicating success from **B**.

If you are working with asynchronous scenarios, you have to test if the queue or TS or database was recorded.

Hope a could help you.